# How do I get my Salesforce org to its original state

Tags: cpq, org

I have implemented some record types and flows in my Salesforce CPQ Developer Org through trailhead. Now I am unable to complete the modules in Trailhead. Therefore, I would like to get the Demo org to its original state where I would be able to continue to work on Trailhead modules in my Salesforce CPQ org.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As far as many things go in life, it's a lot easier to do something than to undo something. In general, if you follow the directions backwards and perform the opposite action (e.g. delete a flow you created), you can work your way back to the original state with some effort.

If you're absolutely stuck, it may be easier to just create a new org. You can link multiple orgs to your account. If you absolutely don't want to keep the old org, you can go into Setup | Company Information | Deactivate Org. It will be deleted after 60 days. You can recover it up to that point.